# Getting a url from database

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, richfaces

Am writing this code to view an email in the browser. I have the URL to the servlet page that will display the email and it works fine. The problem I am having is from tomcat server side. When I fetch the URL from the database, the URL comes as `../somepage` instead of something like `192.672.9.1/somepage`. Is there a way I can have the whole URL? 
Both tomcat and the database are running o the same server .
This what I have so far 
the method for fetching

```
    try {
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            url = rs.getString(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(newemail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    System.out.println("This is the Url for the view inn browser  " + url);
    return url;
}`
```

from the email side I get this

`<td style="text-align:right"><a href="../emailsubscription/browsermail?campid=[mailToviewIdparam]&amp;recipientContactParam=[recipientContactMailParam]">View Mail in Browser </a></td>`

But the print out fro the method gives the correct url including the IP. If I change the IP address to something different from local IP.

I get the correct IP.

Comment: can you please share the relevant code that you have tried so far

Comment: Kindly check the updated question